# Visual Studio Code Install Issue on Ubuntu 17.04: Missing libgconf-2.so.04: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

After installing Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 17.04 through the instructions on [the website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux), I tried to run the program through the command line via `~$ code`, but I received the following error message:

```
/usr/share/code/bin/../code: error while loading shared libraries: 
libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I get Visual Studio Code to run?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to run by installing the required dependency program by typing `~$ sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4` and then by running `~$ code` again.  This time Visual Studio Code opened with no issues.  This answer is based on one of the answers to a similar question posted [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1518).

Comment: Ditto for 18.04